# Использование в качестве ключа шифрования картинки

Tags: криптография

Вопрос навеян "Джони Мнемоником".
Есть ли системы в которых для шифровки данных в качестве ключа используются картинки (или другой тип файлов)?
Как такие системы называются?
Желательно ссылки на описание или статьи по теме.

Comment: Для любой системы ключом могут являться произвольные данные, хоть картинка, хоть фрагмент «Войны и мира». Но: 

* Картинка содержит избыточные данные: значения соседних пикселей близки, поэтому криптоатака на такой ключ легче.
* Ключ обычно обязан иметь фиксированную длину, так что от картинки придётся отбросить лишнее (ну или использовать хвост для уменьшения избыточности).

Comment: Соблаговолите пояснить, в чем суть замечаний. Я не помню в деталях этот фильм (хотя это и не важно). Разве ключ (в виде картинки), предполагается несекретным?

Comment: @VladD на случай когда картинка рассматривается просто как набор байтов разобрались.  
А если картинка векторная и используются математические функции представляющие такое изображение?  
А если на картинке есть токены, расположение которых юзается(например отпечаток пальца или [персики][1])?
А вообще, я сросил как такие системы называются, что бы облегчить мне поиск инфы для изучения, а не насколько актуально юзать бинарный мусор для шифрования.

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: 2 @zenith нет никакой такой категории в которую можна было бы выделить описанные вами подходы к шифрованию данных. как уже писал @VladD картинка это такие же бинарные данные как и любые другие данные на компьютере. Шифрование от этого не меняется меняются только данные которые поступают на вход функции шифрования.

p.s. нет смысла использовать картинки, текстовые файлы в качестве ключа - такие ключи могуть быть подвержены взлому из за определенных закономерностей. Если есть программы которые используют файлы в качестве ключа то скорее за все они берут какой-то хэш от бинарных данных файла

Comment: p.s.s. возможно вас заинтересует "стеганография" - которая изучает возможность использования файлов в качестве контейнера для сокрытия данных (напр. изменить картинку таким образом чтоб она внешне выглядела так же + содержала в себе секретные данные)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да нет никакого специфического обозначения такой процедуре генерации ключа с использованием картинки. Ключи ведь генерируются либо рандомно, либо вычислением хэша некоего слова (пароль+соль) или там чего-то еще. Не вижу никаких проблем в том, чтобы в качестве входного массива данных при вычислении хэша использовать картинку. Это, конечно, несколько неудобно, из-за объема картинки - [зато зрелищно](http://www.kinopoisk.ru/film/3800/). Все равно ключ длиной свыше 1000 бит расколотить сложно, так что ради генерации 1000 бит зачем использовать мегабайт? Достаточно сотню байтов (по максимуму)

Answer (score 0):

Это стандартная возможность и особенность Windows 8 и выше.

[тут можно](https://web.archive.org/web/20150708031610/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8_ru/archive/2011/12/22/signing-picture-password.aspx) почитать про применение...